# Node js authentication function using jwt working fine in postman api but, not giving same result in deployment in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt, mern

This is the validateToken function, which is exported to index.js:

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const accessToken = req.cookies["access-token"];

  if (!accessToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Access token is missing. Please authenticate." });
  }

  verify(accessToken, secret, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: "Failed to authenticate. Invalid access token." });
    }

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

This is the endpoint in index.js:

```
app.get('/profile', validateToken, (req, res) => {
  const username = req.user.username;
  res.json({ username });
});
```

This is the request in ReactJS:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://doitherobb.onrender.com/profile')
    .then((resp) => {
      setStatus('LoggedIn');
      setUsername(resp.data.username);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
        console.log("User is not authenticated.");
        setStatus('LoggedOut');
      } else {
        console.log("Error", err);
      }
    });
}, []);
```

The error is that you're getting the correct data when testing the request with tools like Postman API and Thunder Client, as shown in this image:
[image: Postman API response :]

However, when the same request is made by the client on the deployed website, you're not getting the expected result. The console log shows that the user is not authenticated, as seen in this image:
[image]

Here are the project details:

```
Project repository: https://github.com/sujaltangde/doithero-app
Live project: https://doithero.netlify.app/
Backend API: https://doitherobb.onrender.com/
```

The goal is to get the username from the request on the deployed website, just like you got using Postman API, and make the user authenticated.